# StyledFirebaseAuth (createAuthUri method) receives different request response between two different projects

Tags: firebase, authentication, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I've been building an app using Next JS 13 connected to firebase for a freelance project and using the **StyledFirebaseAuth** from **react-firebaseui/StyledFirebaseAuth** component to take care of my auth. I've run into a problem after trying to migrate my app over to a new firebase project for production, where **StyledFirebaseAuth** will always force me down the account registration flow, even if I use an email address from an account I have created previously. There is no difference between the two projects except that the production firebase project is connected to a Google Cloud project and the dev project is not.

After digging through the request being sent by the **StyledFirebaseAuth** component when it's connected to the firebase dev project vs the production project, I noticed that the **createAuthUri** method from the Google **identityToolkit api** does not return the same response, despite sending the exact same payload. When connected to the dev project, it responds with the following:

```
{
  "kind": "identitytoolkit#CreateAuthUriResponse",
  "allProviders": [
    "password"
  ],
  "registered": true,
  "sessionId": "wR0zw4TO5qPpIgvxrqY_bANyP4s",
  "signinMethods": [
    "password"
  ]
}
```

And when connected to the production project, it responds:

```
{
  "kind": "identitytoolkit#CreateAuthUriResponse",
  "sessionId": "wR0zw4TO5qPpIgvxrqY_bANyP4s"
}
```

Again, the payload for both requests looks to be exactly the same:

**Dev Payload**

```
{identifier: "bob@gmail.com", continueUri: "http://localhost:3000/"}
```

**Production Payload**

```
{identifier: "bob@gmail.com", continueUri: "http://localhost:3000/"}
```

I've also attached the firebase config objects for both projects just incase I'm missing something there:

**DEV CONFIG**

```
let firebaseConfig = {
   apiKey: "AIzaSyCefhN_WDoVg78rqE6xvsxZ2mhog2R9q58",
   authDomain: "wattleartcreations.firebaseapp.com",
   projectId: "wattleartcreations",
   storageBucket: "wattleartcreations.appspot.com",
   messagingSenderId: "947361534354",
   appId: "1:947361534354:web:cf323c4a5c771ad1ceb14b",
   measurementId: "G-X3LFHN1S9C"
};
```

**PRODUCTION CONFIG**

```
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyDVe5PNLzSS0-cNH-lJiecKAuo1PZ6JcNs",
  authDomain: "rare-journey-397519.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "rare-journey-397519",
  storageBucket: "rare-journey-397519.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "905320577101",
  appId: "1:905320577101:web:40a93e1d25e7a9cff20404",
  measurementId: "G-X3LFHN1S9C"
};
```

I've checked to make sure all the correct urls have been whitelisted in both the firebase and Google cloud projects and that the proper auth providers are enabled in the project. I'm guessing that createAuthUri is probably unable to find the email address I'm sending it, but I'm not getting any error responses from the request. I can't figure out why the api is returning different responses between the two projects. Side note, if I call the firebase auth function signinWithEmailAndPassword with the email and password hardcoded in, it works just fine, it's only when using the **StyledFirebaseAuth** component that I run into this issue.

Does anyone have advice on steps I could take to resolve this?

Comment: Did you ever figured this out? Running into exactly the same problem

Comment: I haven’t found a solution. I’m going to try making a new firebase project and reconnecting to it.

Answer (score 0):

If you created your project on or after September 15, 2023, email enumeration protection is enabled by default:

https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/admin/email-enumeration-protection

*A list of sign-in methods for a specified email address is no longer returned when calling the createAuthUri REST API or the fetchSignInMethodsForEmail client SDK method on all platforms.*

To disable email enumeration protection, follow these steps:

In the Google Cloud console, print an access token for your project ID using gcloud auth print-access-token command:

```
gcloud auth print-access-token --project=PROJECT_ID
```

Disable email enumeration protection using the Identity Toolkit API:

```
curl -X PATCH -d "{'emailPrivacyConfig':{'enableImprovedEmailPrivacy':false}}" \
    -H 'Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN' \
    -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'X-Goog-User-Project: PROJECT_ID' \
    "https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/admin/v2/projects/PROJECT_ID/config?updateMask=emailPrivacyConfig"
```